# How to use AndroidAnnotation @FragmentArg with Kotlin?

Tags: android-fragments, kotlin, android-annotations

How can I use `@FragmentArg` from `AndroidAnnotations` within `Kotlin` fragment?

```
@EFragment(R.layout.debug_empty_fragment)
open class EmptyFragment : Fragment(){

    @FragmentArg("debugIndex")
    var debugIndex:Int = 0
}
```

This gives me following gradle error:

```
error: org.androidannotations.annotations.FragmentArg cannot be used on a private element
```

I tried making *debugIndex* `open` <strike>(public)</strike>, but it is not working. Any ideas? Is this even possible?

I`m using Android Annotations 4.3.1 and kotlin 1.1.2-5

Comment: You misunderstood what `open` keyword does. It doesn't make the field or class public -- it allows overriding (in Kotlin by default fields and classes are `final`, you can "un-final" them by using the `open` keyword)

Comment: thanks for hint, but `un-final` them with `open` doesn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, `@JvmField` is your friend. ([further information](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-field/))

> Instructs the Kotlin compiler not to generate getters/setters for this property and expose it as a field.

So `@FragmentArg` should look like this

```
@JvmField
@FragmentArg("debugIndex")
var debugIndex:Int = 0
```